# sas scan function with macro array

Tags: sas

I have a macro array &start_num

```
+-------+
| start |
+-------+
|  25.5 |
|  33.5 |
|  42.5 |
|  54.5 |
|    98 |
+-------+
```

but when I am using

```
%put %scan(&start_num,1);
```

it returns :25

```
%put %scan(&start_num,2);
```

returns me:533

why and how to fix it?

Comment: How is start_num assigned ?  You don't have a macro array because there is no such thing in macro.  You would use %scan to retrieve an item from a concatenation of items.  The 533 you show is either hiding a separator or show a lack of separation within the concatenated items.  When there is a space separator use third arg to specify the delimiter `%scan(%start_num, 1, %str( ))`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify [delimiter](https://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=p0jshdjy2z9zdzn1h7k90u99lyq6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) in `scan` function.

For example,if macro variable were initialized from variable `start` in table:

```
proc sql noprint;
   select start into:start_num separated by ' ' from have;
quit;
```

> START_NUM=25.5 33.5 42.5 54.5 98

Or in `%let` statement:

```
%let START_NUM=25.5 33.5 42.5 54.5 98;
```

Using `%scan` function:

```
%let var1 = %scan(&start_num,1,%str( ));
%put &=var1;
```

> VAR1=25.5

```
%let var2 = %scan(&start_num,2,%str( ));
%put &=var2;
```

> VAR2=33.5

Answer (score 0):

because %scan thinks dot as seperator, that is why you get 25 and 533 respectively. checkout below example

```
%let start_num= 25.533.545.554.598;
%let var1 = %scan(&start_num,1);
%put value of with dot as separator &var1;
```

%put &var1 yields 25

```
 %let var2 = %scan(&start_num,2);
 %put value of with dot as separator &var2;
```

%put &var2 yields 533